# Нахождение последней буквы в слове

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string str;
    char a;
    int k = 0;
    cin >> str;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        a = str.length() - 1;        // проблема вот тут
        if (str[i] == a)
            k++;
    }
    cout << k;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Нужно найти сколько раз последняя буква слова встречается в самом слове. Хочу вот тут через "а" обозначить последнюю букву, но не знаю как. Не могу додуматься. Подскажете?

Comment: @navi1893, Вы также интересовались подсчетом количества строк в файле. Ниже см. мой ответ по этому поводу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
string str;
int k = 0;
cin >> str;

for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++)
{
        if (str[i] == str[str.length()-1]) k++;
}
cout << k;
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: такое впервые вижу. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: к `str[str.length()-1]` вы обращаетесь `str.length()` раз, хотя можно было свести к единице

Comment: @Spectre Думаю, что любой адекватный компилятор соптимизит вызов `length()` и  вынесет его за цикл. Хотя, конечно, сделать это здесь самостоятельно было бы лучше.

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы в файле он проверил количество строк? Я вот просто не знаю как обозначить строки, т.е хочу писать: если "строка" == "\n") k++; Подскажете? Как обозначить строки?

Answer (score 2):

Как и обещал, после футбола.

Сначала думал сделать маленький обучающий набросок для [[[[@navi1893](/users/4969/navi1893)](/users/4969/navi1893)](/users/4969/navi1893)](/users/4969/navi1893), и 
начал просто писать варианты программки подсчета количества строк, но заинтересовался временем их выполнения.

Не могу не поделиться результатами.

Программка на С++. Делал в MinGW g++ на Win 7, а потом в Linux g++ под VBox на той же машине (I5-2500 3.30 Ghz).

Итак, сама программка (файл lines.cpp)
В ней в комментариях сведения о времени исполнения в Windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" long long mtime();

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  long long start = mtime();
  int k = 0,  ci, co = 0, 
    how = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): 0;
  char c;
  string s;

  /* 10000001 lines (88888904 bytes)  Windows 7 I5-2500 3.30 GHz */

  switch (how) {

  case 0:
    cout << "getchar() countlines\n";
    /* 700 msec  */
    while ((ci = getchar()) != EOF) {
      co = ci;
      if (ci == '\n')
    k++;
    }
    if (co && co != '\n')
      k++;
    break;

  case 1:
    cout << "cin.get(char) countlines\n";
    /* 10300 msec */
    while (cin.get(c) && !cin.eof()) {
      co = c;
      if (c == '\n')
    k++;
    }
    if (co && co != '\n')
      k++;
    break;

  case 2:
    cout << "read(0,char *,4096) countlines\n";
    /* 450 msec */
    int  len, llen;
    char buf[4096];

    llen = 0;
    while (len = read(0,buf,sizeof(buf))) {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (buf[i] == '\n')
      k++;
      }
      llen = len;
    }
    if (llen && buf[llen-1] != '\n')
      k++;
    break;

  default:
    cout << "getline(cin,string) countlines\n";
    /* 14150 msec */
    while (!cin.eof()) {
      getline(cin,s);
      if (cin.good() || s.length())
    k++;
    }
  }

  cout <<k<< " lines\n" << mtime()-start <<" msec\n";

  exit(0);
}
```

Как видно реализуется 4 способа (почти одинаковых) подсчета количества строк.

Программка создания тестового файла (файл mkli.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): 10000000;
  if (n <= 0)
    n = 1000;
  printf ("n = %d\n",n);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("%d\n",i);
  exit (0);
}
```

Текст функции для замера времени в миллисекундах (файл mtime.c)

```
/*
  время в миллисекундах

 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}
```

А вот протокол трансляции и запуска программ в Linux (и времена исполнения в нем)

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc -c mtime.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc mkli.c -o mkli
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ lines.cpp mtime.o -o lines
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./mkli >li.tst 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ wc li.tst
10000001 10000003 78888903 li.tst
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./lines 0 < li.tst 
getchar() countlines
10000001 lines
685 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./lines 1 < li.tst 
cin.get(char) countlines
10000001 lines
3101 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./lines 2 < li.tst 
read(0,char *,4096) countlines
10000001 lines
225 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./lines 3 < li.tst 
getline(cin,string) countlines
10000001 lines
2732 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Надеюсь, будет познавательно.

**UPDATE 1**

Специально для [[[[@navi1893](/users/4969/navi1893)](/users/4969/navi1893)](/users/4969/navi1893)](/users/4969/navi1893).

Файл navinl.cpp

```
$ g++ navinl.cpp -o navinl 
$ ./navinl.exe < navinl.cpp 
21 lines
$

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int ci, co = 0, k = 0;

  while ((ci = getchar()) != EOF) {
    co = ci;
    if (ci == '\n')
      k++;
  }
  if (co && co != '\n')
    k++;

  cout <<k<< " lines\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Насчет переменных **ci** и **co**.

Строки в файле разделяются символом '\n'. Казалось бы, для определения количества строк достаточно посчитать количество символов NEWLINE в файле.

Однако, если **последняя** порция данных в файле **не** завершается '\n', то ее в качестве строки (при "очевидном" алгоритме) мы не учтем. Поэтому после обнаружения конца файла, надо проверить - был ли последним символом в файле '\n' или нет. Для этой цели используем переменную **co**, в которой сохраняем последний прочитанный символ.

Почему для чтения файла (стандартного входа) используется libc getchar() IMHO очевидно из предыдущего материала.

Comment: а можно для моего именно случая чтоб вы написали и в более понятной форме? А то так непонятно мне, да и длинно чет выходит

Comment: Какой-то чересчур раздутый у вас код получился...чересчур...

Comment: @Asen, чересчур раздутый для 4-х вариантов подсчета количества строк ?

Возможно. С удовольствием посмотрю на более компактный.

Comment: @avp видимо ТС учиться не хочет, а хочет, чтобы за него сделали * facepalm *

Comment: да и длинно чет выходит

@navi1893, вам не нужно всё, только case 2 - он самый быстрый

Answer (score 1):

Почему же вы все так и норовите идти сишными путями? Это не всегда хорошо, а иногда - фатально плохо. Цикл `for`, например, в вашем коде - напрочь убивает любую, даже мизерную, гибкость...хорошо, что хоть класс `String` юзаете, а не указатели на строки...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string word = "fuck yeah this is a sentense";  // наше слово
char letter = word[word.size()-1];             // последняя буква

int count = 0;
int pos = word.find(letter);
while(pos!=string::npos)
{
                  count++;
                  pos = word.find(letter,pos+1);      
                        }

cout<<count<<endl;
cout<<"Letter '"<<letter<<"' returns in the word "<<count<<" times."<<endl;

system("Pause");
}
```

---

**UPD:**

```
ifstream f("file.txt");
string s = "";
int c = 0; 
while(!f.eof())
{
               f>>s;
               c++;
               }
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы в файле он проверил количество строк? Я вот просто не знаю как обозначить строки, т.е хочу писать: если "строка" == "n") k++; Подскажете? Как обозначить строки?

Comment: Посмотрите в дополнении к моему ответу. Это псевдокод.

Comment: а нельзя так:
    string line;
    while( ! file.eof())
        {
             if ( line == "\n" )            
             k++;             
        }
    cout << k;
???

Comment: @navi1893 вы должны считать строку line (f>>line)

Comment: Просто я вот так сделал:

    #include <iostream>  
    #include <fstream>  
    #include <string>  
    using namespace std;  
    int main()  
    {  
    ifstream file("C:\input.txt");  
    string line = "";  
    int k = 1;  
    while( ! file.eof())  
    {  
             if ( line == "\n" )              
             k++;              
    }  
    cout << k;  
    system("PAUSE");  
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}И он у меня ничего не выводит, замерзает

Comment: @Asen Вот, в правильном направлении движетесь. Использование `std::string.find` здесь уместно и хорошо выглядит.

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey, это само собой !

Comment: @navi1893

![][1]

[1]: http://i.imgur.com/dQRxu.jpg

Comment: @navi1893, Вы в цикле **while** ***ничего не читаете*** из файла. Вот и "замерзает".

Кстати, читать строки лучше функцией **getline** и проверять на '\\n' тогда не надо.

Comment: @navi1893, я полностью соглашусь с @Котикхочеткушать...

    while( ! file.eof())  
{  
         if ( line == "\n" )              
         k++;              
}

Comment: Ну вам уже и я показал в дополнении своего ответа, и @avp сказал...видимо, проблема не в ваших вопросах =)

Comment: @navi1893, делайте проще, чтитайте в цикле файл построчно

    while (!file.eof()) { getline(file,line); k++; }

Не самый эффективный способ подсчета строк, но тут уж не до жиру...

Comment: @navi1893, распечатайте перед Вашим **for** значение file.eof(), успокойтесь и подумайте полчасика. Потом получится.

Comment: @avp @asen кто нибудь помогите, а то никак не могу!(

Comment: @navi1893, после футбола.